# azure-ad-b2c post signup flow

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I'm building a webapp that uses Azure AD B2C authentication. I'd like to implement a feature such that any new user signing up always lands at a specific controller action. How should I configure my policies to ensure this. For example /account/newuser should be invoked everytime a new signup policy is executed.

Also, if I have the [Authorize] attribute set for an action and a new user lands there, how can i ensure that the sign up, not the sign in policy is executed?

Comment: I'm using the Reply URL on the policy page to trigger the action when the SignUp policy is executed. I'm really looking for best practice to ensure that every new user always has to sign up even if they do not explicitly click the sign up link (which triggers the sign up policy).

Comment: Have you seen the unified sign in and up policy?

Answer (score 0):

There is a built-in claim "newUser" that you can select in the 'Signup'/'sign-up or sign-in' policy that is made exactly for this scenario.

This claim will be returned only once after the user sign-up. You can inspect the claim once the user get redirected to your application and if this claim exists with a value of "true" then redirect your user to the specific controller.

In your Azure B2C directory, select your sign-up policy --> Edit --> Application Claims then check the "User is new" as in the image below:

[image]